# Socket.io with redis store emits events in the callback function consume of AMQP

Tags: node.js, redis, socket.io, socket.io-redis

I want to use `nodejs` server to receive messages from `AMQP`, then push those messages to web page through `socket.io` with `redis`.

The `emit()` function is invoked in the callback function `consume` of AMQP, and web UI can get those data. However, I can NOT find any data in `redis`?

codes

```
var redisPort = 6379,
    redisHost = 'localhost';

var app = require('express')(),
    http = require('http').Server(app),
    io = require('socket.io')(http),
    redisAdapter = require('socket.io-redis'),
    redis = require('redis');

var
    pub = redis.createClient(redisPort, redisHost),
    sub = redis.createClient(redisPort, redisHost, {detect_buffers: true});

//
io.adapter( redisAdapter({pubClient: pub, subClient: sub}) );

app.get('/', function(req, res){

    res.sendFile('index.html');
});

io.on('connection', function(socket){
    console.log("web socket connection ...");

    socket.join('room');

    socket.on('disconnect', function(){
        console.log("socketio diconnect...");
    });
});
```

call back function in `AMQP`

```
function response(msg){
    io.to('room').emit('online', msg);
}

...

ch.consume(queue, response, {noAck: true});
```

Am I right to use this API `emit()`? or miss any good trick?